# How can I add a image/shape in navigation bar?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

I need to put shape or image that can when it scroll up or down it will never move in its position and it float it until navigation to footer.

Like this one a heart that fixed in every part of the website.

Without using spfx because i have a restriction installing anything in the pc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can develop a [SPFx Application Customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension) for adding the floating image/icon on all modern pages in SharePoint online.

Here's one SPFx extension sample which does similar things & will help you to get started with: [Table Of Contents for SharePoint](https://gitlab.lsonline.fr/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/toc)

[image]

---

Also check for SPFx samples given in below GitHub repositories which might help you:

1. [sp-dev-fx-extensions](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/)
2. [sp-dev-fx-webparts](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/)

Comment: Hi @sweetcha143, does this answer help you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing , unfortunately we cannot add a shape or image in SharePoint navigation bar. Here are a few things we can do:

1. Change the look of your page's navigation style, colors, and logo.
2. On a team site you can add, edit, or remove links on the navigation menu.
3. Edit the horizontal menu, footer menu (communication site only), or the hub site navigation bar that appears on all communication sites associated with a hub site.
4. Target navigational links to specific audiences with modern SharePoint in Microsoft 365 audience targeting.
5. Set up a multilingual site name, navigation and footer on Communication sites.

You can refer to this article: [Customize the navigation on your SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca)

Thanks for your understanding.

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved .If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.